# Marking a Vue Todo List Item as done

Tags: vuejs2

This may have been answered before, but I have been unable to find an answer that works in this specific situation.

I'm new to Vue and trying to build a Todo list in which I can click on a list item when it is complete, changing or adding a class that will change the style of the item.

I guess I don't fully understand how the scopes work together between the main Vue and a component. The code I have right now does absolutely nothing. I have tried moving methods between the main and component, but it always gives me some error.

I guess I'm just looking for some guidance as to how this should be done.

```js
Vue.component('todo-item', {
 props: ['todo'],
 template: '<li>{{ todo.id + 1 }}. {{ todo.text }}</li>'
})

var app = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data: {
  isDone: false,
  todos: [
   { id: 0, text: 'This is an item to do today' },
   { id: 1, text: 'This is an item to do today' },
   { id: 2, text: 'This is an item to do today' },
   { id: 3, text: 'This is an item to do today' },
   { id: 4, text: 'This is an item to do today' },
   { id: 5, text: 'This is an item to do today' }
  ]
 },
 methods: {
  markDone: function(todo) {
   console.log(todo)
   this.isDone = true
  }
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="flex">
      <todo-item 
        v-for="todo in todos"
        :todo="todo"
        :key="todo.id"
        @click="markDone"
        :class="{'done': isDone}"
      ></todo-item>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help, guys.

Comment: try this: uses one array/map/object to store which to-do already completed, or add one property like 'done' to each element of data-property=`todos`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were getting so close! You simply had your `:class="{'done': isDone}" @click="markDone"` in the wrong place!

The important thing to remember with components is that each one has to have their own data. In your case, you were binding all `todo`'s to your root Vue instance's `done` variable. You want to instead bind each one to their own `done` variable in their own data.

The way you do this is by creating a function version of `data` that returns individual data for each component. It would look like this:

```
data () {
    return {
      isDone: false,
    }
  },
```

And then you move the `:class="{'done': isDone}` from the `todo` to the `li` internal to it:

```
<li :class="{'done': isDone}">{{ todo.id + 1 }}. {{ todo.text }}</li>
```

Now we have the 'done' class depending on an individual data piece for each individual `todo` element. All we need to do now is be able to mark it as complete. So we also want each `todo` component to have it's own method to do so. Add a `methods:` object to your `todo` component and move your `markDone` method there:

```
methods: {
    markDone() {
      this.isDone = true;
    },
  }
```

Now move the `@click="markDone"` to the `li` as well:

```
<li :class="{'done': isDone}" @click="markDone">{{ todo.id + 1 }}. {{ todo.text }}</li>
```

And there you go! Now you should be able to create as many `todo`'s as you want, and mark them all complete!

**Bonus:**

Consider changing your function to `toggleDone() { this.isDone = !this.isDone; }`, that way you can toggle them back and forth between done and not done!

Full code below :)

```js
Vue.component('todo-item', {
 props: ['todo'],
 template: `<li :class="{'done': isDone}" @click="toggleDone">{{ todo.id + 1 }}. {{ todo.text }}</li>`,
  data () {
    return {
      isDone: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleDone() {
      this.isDone = !this.isDone;
    },
  }
})

var app = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data: {
  isDone: false,
  todos: [
   { id: 0, text: 'This is an item to do today' },
   { id: 1, text: 'This is an item to do today' },
   { id: 2, text: 'This is an item to do today' },
   { id: 3, text: 'This is an item to do today' },
   { id: 4, text: 'This is an item to do today' },
   { id: 5, text: 'This is an item to do today' }
  ]
 },
 methods: {
  markDone: function(todo) {
   console.log(todo)
   this.isDone = true
  }
 }
})
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="flex">
      <todo-item 
        v-for="todo in todos"
        :todo="todo"
        :key="todo.id"
      ></todo-item>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, which are handling with the click event is the `<li>` element, but your are trying to handle it in the root of your component, there're a few ways to solve this

**Use *native* modifier**

```
<todo-item 
    v-for="todo in todos"
    :todo="todo"
    :key="todo.id"
    @click.native="markDone"
    :class="{'done': isDone}"
>
</todo-item>
```

You can find more info here
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Listening-for-Native-Events-on-Components-with-v-on-changed

**Emit from component the click event**

```
Vue.component('todo-item', {
  props: ['todo'],
  template: '<li @click="click()">{{ todo.id + 1 }}. {{ todo.text }}</li>',
  methods: {
    click () {
      this.$emit('click')
    }
  }
})
```

By the way, in your current code once you click in one todo all the todos will be "marked as done" as you are using just one variable for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your current implementation will affect all items in the list when you mark one item as done because you are associating a single `isDone` property to all the items and when that property becomes true, it will be applied to all the items in your list.

So to fix that, you need to find a way to associate `done` to each item. And because your item is an `object`, you just assign a new property `done` dynamically and set the value to true which means it is marked as done. It will be very confusing to just explain it, so I included a full example using your existing code.

See this JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/205021/